# How provide indexing to any array in php

Tags: php, array-intersect

i am trying to compare two arrays using php intersect function.
I am using following code

```
$input_array=array();
$input_array=explode("," , $_POST['list']);
$array = array();
$result1 =mysql_query("SELECT b_no FROM abc");

while($fetch_array=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $array[] = $fetch_array['b_no'];
}

$result=array_intersect($input_array,$array);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo"</pre>";
```

and result is like this:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 443829
    [5] => 952040
)
```

The resultant array have not their own indexing. Is possible to provide indexing?

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to provide indexing, but you will need to specify which indexing you want.

If the resulting indexing is not what you expected, please note that [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) only compares the values of each array, and it retains the index or key from the first array of each match.

If your requirement is to also match on the keys of an associative array (although I am inferring you are not judging from your example) you can use [`array_intersect_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php).

If you want to simply 'reset' the indexing you can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). For example:

```
<?php

$a = [2 => 1, 2, 3];
$b = [2, 3, 4];

$intersect = array_intersect($a, $b);

print_r($intersect);

// Original keys are retained:
//
// Array
// (
//     [3] => 2
//     [4] => 3
// )

print_r(array_values($intersect));

// Original keys are discarded:
//
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 2
//     [1] => 3
// )
```

On the other hand, if you had a specific set of keys you wanted to use, say for example `['foo', 'bar']` you can use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) - it accepts two arrays, one as keys and the other as values, to explicitly define a new set of indexes or keys for an array. For example:

```
$keys = ['foo', 'bar'];
print_r(array_combine($keys, $intersect);

// Array
// (
//     [foo] => 2
//     [bar] => 3
// )

$indexes = [100, 200];
print_r(array_combine($indexes, $intersect));

// Array
// (
//    [100] => 2
//    [200] => 3
// )
```

Please note, `array_combine()` requires that the length of both arrays are the same. I cannot really provide any more detail unless you update your question but I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks.actually i need to use index value in for loop so that i can retrieve other attribute data from mysql table.Can you guide me how is possible??

Comment: I can, but only if you update your answer to explain what you mean in more detail - specifically if you can provide example input data and the result you expect.